# Optimization: 2 Objective Constraints

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, solver

I am working on an optimization problem.  The objective is to determine the optimal number of target hires (COUNT below) to set per recruitment sourcing channel that would yield the lowest number of attritors (ATTRITORS below) at the end of each month and at the minimum sourcing cost (COST below). The constraints would be that the the total Count should equal 600 and that all channels should be utilized.

Given the two objective functions, is this something that can be accomplished using R, Solver, or any open source tool?

I tried formatting a dummy data and it would look something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVjiV.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way of dealing with this problem is to quantify the attrition cost. You already have `cost per hire`, in the same way using your domain knowledge and business conversation try to come up with `per employee attrition cost` (say first model). More likely depending on skill level `per employee attrition cost` will be different so for the sake of good approximation you may want to calculate it for each channel and then do average (say second model)

Once you say got `per employee attrition cost` regardless of channel (first model) then you can simply add `per employee attrition cost * total attrition` in objective function. In second level model you can do same thing; with channel dimension added, `per employee attrition cost for a channel * total attrition for that channel`. Based on business interpretation people also go next level: `factor * per employee attrition cost for a channel * total attrition for that channel` where `factor` is to adjust the importance of hiring and attrition cost (though I would expect cost to tackle this alone).

you can do this in excel solver OR choose here https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html OR go for commercial solvers like Gurobi, CPLEX with their APIs in R, Python.

Comment: Thank you! Multiplying employee attrition cost * total attrition would certainly do it. However I intend to add an additional variable, Conversion Rate (in percentage). Such that, channels with low conversion rates should ideally be prioritized less. Do I just multiply the three cost * total attrition * (1-conversion rate) then minimize this product?

Comment: Yes thats correct. Then you need to this modelling at channel level which will be `per employee attrition cost for a channel * total attrition for that channel * (1-conversion rate for channel)` ; as per your statement conversion rate is channel specific thing.

Comment: Thanks abhiieor. But sorry to clarify, what do you mean by modelling it 'per employee at channel level'? You mean I have to compute for different costs per employee and then aggregate it back? Because if so, I can do it for one month. But then data should vary month on month. Couldn't I do it initially at aggregated level as in the attached image in my original question?

Comment: `per employee attrition cost for a channel` is simply avg attrition cost incurred per employee who was hired thru channel 1. Now the decision you need to make is; if you want to consider all till date attritions to calculate this or this year's attritions or last 6 month or last 3 month's attritions. Point here is this is very flexible measure as per your definition